# How to serialize/deserialize space-separated string into data struct?

Tags: rust, serde

For example, I have a string `dog 5 true` and want to serialize it into a Rust data struct using serde:

```
struct Pet {
    pub name: String,
    pub age: u32,
    pub alive: bool,
}
```

Is it possible? If it is, how to accomplish that with Serde custom deserializer?

Comment: Is that data format required? You might run into issues with determining if a space is continuing a String or separating fields. But on the other hand if you are able to change the formatting, why not use an existing format like CBOR, JSON, or RON?

Comment: Yeah it's required, and it's probably better to just parse it manually

Comment: The [duplicate applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1fa2d598fead8fab9d8c48fe169e4477)